# How to search through tree to find the maximum sum of a set of nodes' value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

```
         G
     B
         H


A    D

         E

     C   I

         F

1    2   3 (level)
```

Suppose there is a Tree in the above structure.
Each node is linked with the nodes of their parent and children. Also each node is linked with one node previously added and somewhat related to the current node.

Suppose now that each node has five properties:

1. the name of the node (e.g. 'A', 'B', 'C', etc)
2. the node of their parent (e.g. if `node.name == 'B'`, then `node.parent.name == 'A'` is True)
3. the node beneath them (e.g. if `node.name == 'G'`, then `node.previous.name == 'H'` is True, However if `node.name == 'H'`, then `node.previous.name == 'B'` is True)
4. list of children nodes (e.g. if `node.name == 'A'`, then `[c.name for c in node.children] == ['B', 'D', 'C']` is True)
5. node.value (e.g. isinstance(node.value, int) is True)

Now if I want to search through the Tree to find the maximum value of a group of related nodes with the given number n which denotes the group size.
(e.g. node E relates to node I and node C, but node F, however, node I doesn't relate to node E, but does relate to node F and node C)

How exactly can I design this function

Comment: What does it mean for a node to be related to another node? Is a node only related to its parent node and the previous node?

Comment: @YellowBird , A node related to all of its children, its parent, and the node that joined previously which is either the one right below it or its parent.

Comment: @SebastianY. What does it mean for "n".

Comment: @jiahilegass, I want a function that is to find the maximum of all possible sum of n related node. However I just can't figure out how to design such function

Comment: Is it means you want to find groups, such as "B A G H" or "C A D E I F" if the sum of their values equels to n and the function return 6?

Comment: @jiahilegass, somewhat like that. one possible combination is A B G H if n = 4, another is D A C E I F if n = 6.

Comment: Do you have any bounds on the number of nodes and n?

Comment: @YellowBird, That's the problem. I would say there is no bounds on the number of nodes and n. However, for the use of this function, we can just consider the number of nodes is a manageable number, which shouldn't be too big

Comment: The size of n is rather important, can it be e.g. (number of nodes)/2?

Comment: @YellowBird, it is definitely smaller than the size of nodes, but it is can be greater than size_of_nodes/2

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Here is my understanding of your problem: You want to enumerate all groups of related nodes of size n, and find the maximum sum of the values of the nodes in such a group.</strike>

Here is an algorithm:
For each node keep a sorted list of its children, sorted with respect to the values of the children. Iterate over all the nodes. For each node,
compute the maximum of the following four numbers:

1. current node + largest n-1 children
2. current node + largest n-2 children + parent
3. current node + largest n-2 children + previous
4. current node + largest n-3 children + parent + previous

Remember to take care of special cases, e.g., if a node has few children, parent=previous etc.
(actually you might just put all related nodes of a node in one sorted list and pick the n-1 largest).

---

Since a node apparently can be related to its childrens children, the above will not work.

---

I have given it another go:
For each node keep a list `l`, whose index is the maximum value obtained using the node + up to i-1 children.
For each leaf node this is simply going to be `[0, leaf.value, ...]`.
For each node, assume that is has one child. Then `node.l` is easy to compute, it is simply:

```
node.l[i] = child.l[i-1] + node.value
```

If we then add another child to this node, we may use 0 through n-1 nodes from the child, depeneding on what is optimal. This is computed using (kind of, see the code below)

```
node.l[i] = max(node.l[i], node.l[i-k] + child.l[i])
```

This is implemented below.
It is easy to accomodate for the extra connectedness due to `node.previous`. We just make an extra pass through the list of nodes at the end, when all `node.l`'s are computed.

```
for node in nodes:
    # l[i] = maximum value obatined using node + up to i-1 children
    node.l = [0 for i in xrange(n+1)]
    node.visited = False

Q = [] # Queue
for leaf in nodes:
    if len(leaf.children) > 0: continue
    Q.append(leaf)
    leaf.visited = True

while Q:
    t = Q.pop(0)
    l = [0]
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        l.append(t[i-1] + t.value)
    t.l = l
    if not t.parent: break
    for l in xrange(0, n+1):
        for i in xrange(l, n+1):
            t.parent.l[i] = max(t.parent[i], t.parent[i-l] + t[l])
    if not t.parent.visited:
        t.parent.visited = True
        Q.append(t.parent)

m = 0
for node in nodes:
    m = max(m, node[n], node[n-1] \
            + (node.previous.value if node.previous else 0))
print m
```

The running time is `n*n*(number of nodes)`.